# Не работает manage.py на PythonAnywhere, но на локально все норм

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, pythonanywhere

Зашел на сайт PythonAnywhere, и там попытался импортировать Django. Вроде получилось, но когда вызываю команду python manage.py migrate, пишет: Invalid Syntax, Line 14.

Вот код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'LastSite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ) from exc
               execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: На pythonanywhere у вас точно настроено выполнение с помощью Python3 а не Python2?

Comment: @insolor нет, а как это сделать?

Comment: Вкладка web, слева должно быть выбрано ваше приложение (если оно одно, то оно и будет выбрано), крутите вниз до раздела Code, меняете Python version на нужную версию. Еще в самом файле `manage.py` желательно в первой строке тоже прописать `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6` (или нужную вам версию).

Comment: @insolor а как  добавить файлы в приложение? Я просто загрузил в папку files. Я в PythonAnywere вообще ничего не понимаю прост.

Comment: Когда создаете приложение Django, создается директория `/home/insolor/mysite` (где вместо insolor имя вашего пользователя, имя директории может отличаться, но по-умолчанию такое). В нее складываете ваши файлы. Если только начинаете, лучше вообще пересоздать приложение с нужной версией Python, чтобы не возникло каких-нибудь неожиданностей.

Comment: Для статических и медифайлов есть свои директории, это в настройках приложения можно посмотреть.

Comment: @insolor спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в консоли pythonanywhere перейти в директорию проекта и создать виртуальное окружение, после этого активировать его, установить все пакеты и в активированном окружении уже выполнять python manage.py migrate. Также в разделе web на pythonanywhere нужно в соответствующем поле указать путь к вашему виртуальному окружению. Потом  крутите вниз до раздела Code и меняете Python version на нужную версию, как было сказано выше

**А вообще просто попробуйте вместо python manage.py migrate выполнить python3 manage.py migrate**